# How to render graphicImage in dataTable based on a column value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I have a dataTable, containing Package objects with id and phaseList attributes. I would like this dataTable to display package id and its five phases status with some graphicImages like colored circles.

For example: If a package's phase one is completed, the first circle rendered in a progress column is a green one, other four are red ones.

So basically I need to render a circle based on a value from phaseList element attribute. I already accomplished all of this, but it seems to me that there should be some other way. The problem is that I must have five phase color attributes in a backing bean and five getters and setters for those attributes (see code below). In those getters there is very similar code for all five attributes, so I thought I should have just one color attribute and one getter and there should somehow get an information which circle is currently rendered.

Is there any other way (with less duplicated code) to render those circles?

```
public class Package implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal id;              
    private List<PhaseStatus> phaseList;    

    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPhaseList(List<PhaseStatus> phaseList) {
        this.phaseList= phaseList;
    }

    public List<PhaseStatus> getPhaseList() {
        return phaseList;
    }

}
```

PhaseStatus class:

```
public class PhaseStatus implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal phaseId;
    private BigDecimal phaseStatus;
    private String hint;

    public void setPhaseId(BigDecimal phaseId) {
        this.phaseId = phaseId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPhaseId() {
        return phaseId;
    }

    public void setPhaseStatus(BigDecimal phaseStatus) {
        this.phaseStatus = phaseStatus;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPhaseStatus() {
        return phaseStatus;
    }

    public void setHint(String hint) {
        this.hint = hint;
    }

    public String getHint() {
        return hint;
    }   
}
```

Xhtml code:

```
<p:column headerText="Id">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{item.id}" />
</p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Progress">
        <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase1">
            <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseOneColor}" width="24px" height="24px" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip id="hint1" for="lnkPhase1" value="#{bean.phaseOneHint}" />

        <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase2">
            <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseTwoColor}" width="24px" height="24px" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip id="hint2" for="lnkPhase2" value="#{bean.phaseTwoHint}" />

        <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase3">
            <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseThreeColor}" width="24px" height="24px" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip id="hint3" for="lnkPhase3" value="#{bean.phaseThreeHint}" />

        <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase4">
            <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseFourColor}" width="24px" height="24px" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip id="hint4" for="lnkPhase4" value="#{bean.phaseFourHint}" />

        <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase5">
            <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseFiveColor}" width="24px" height="24px" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <p:tooltip id="hint5" for="lnkPhase5" value="#{bean.phaseFiveHint}" />
    </p:column>
```

Part of my backing bean:

```
private String phaseOneColor;
private String phaseTwoColor;
private String phaseThreeColor;
private String phaseFourColor;
private String phaseFiveColor;
private DataTable dtPackages;
```

one of the getter's:

```
public String getPhaseOneColor() {
    Package myPackage = (Package) getDtPackages().getRowData();
    List<PhaseStatus> list = myPackage.getPhaseList();
    BigDecimal status = list.get(0).getPhaseStatus();
    if (status != null) {
        switch (status.intValue()) {
            case 1:
                phaseOneColor = "green.png";
                break;
            default:
                phaseOneColor = "red.png";
                break;
        }
    } else {
        phaseOneColor = "red.png";
    }

    return phaseOneColor;
}
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.

Comment: Yes, it is. I changed the variable names before I posted the question just to be easier to understand the whole code. You are right,  I wasn't careful about that. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this

```
public String getPhaseColor(int phase) {
    Package package = (Package) getDtPackages().getRowData();
    List<PhaseStatus> list = package.getPhaseList();
    BigDecimal status = list.get(phase).getPhaseStatus();
    if (status != null) {
        switch (status.intValue()) {
            case 1:
                phaseColor = "green.png";
                break;
            default:
                phaseColor = "red.png";
                break;
        }
    } else {
        phaseColor = "red.png";
    }

    return phaseColor;
}
```

Similar for tooltips

```
public String getPhaseTooltip(int phase) {
    Package package = (Package) getDtPackages().getRowData();
    List<PhaseStatus> list = package.getPhaseList();
    BigDecimal status = list.get(phase).getPhaseStatus();
    String tooltip = null;
    if (status != null) {
        switch (status.intValue()) {
            case n: 
                tooltip = "Phase " + phase + " tooltip";
                break;
            default:
        }
    } else {
        tooltip = "probably error";
    }

    return tooltip;
}
```

And you use this in page like this

```
<p:column headerText="Progress">
  <ui:repeat var="phase" value="#{item.phaseList}" varStatus="status">

    <p:commandLink id="lnkPhase#{status.index + 1}">
        <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.getPhaseColor(status.index + 1)}" width="24px" height="24px" />
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:tooltip id="hint#{status.index + 1}" for="lnkPhase#{status.index + 1}" value="#{bean.getPhaseTooltip(status.index + 1)}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

There might be some errors in the code since I'm typing it in here directly, but you'll get the idea.

**UPDATE**

For Java 5 (method invocations with parameters doesn't work), you could do something like this

```
public Map<Integer, String> getPhaseColors() {
    Package package = (Package) getDtPackages().getRowData();
    Map<Integer, String> phaseColors = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    if (package != null) {
        List<PhaseStatus> list = package.getPhaseList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++;) {
            BigDecimal ps = list.get(i).getPhaseStatus();
            if (ps != null) {
                phaseColors.put(i, ps.intValue() == 1 ? "green.png" : "red.png");
            } else {
                phaseColors.put(i, "red.png");
            }
        }
    }

    return phaseColor;
}

<p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseColors[status.index + 1]}" width="24px" height="24px" />
```

Similar for tooltips.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I thought about that solution but I believe EL method invocation with parameters is not available in Java EE 5, right?

Comment: Getter returns right values, but when the phase circle is rendered, I get NulPointerException. I tried this solution on the first phase circle for now, like this: <p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseColors[0]}" width="24px" height="24px" /> That is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `package` or `phaseStatus` are probably null at some point, just try to check for it. I've edited my answer to check for null values.

Comment: I don't think `package` or `phaseStatus` are null because I'm logging the phaseColors value before `return`. The first package has five phases and it logs `{0=green.png, 1=red.png, 2=red.png, 3=red.png, 4=red.png}`, which is correct. So the key '0' has it's value in a phaseColors map. If those values are correctly read, there can't be any `package` or `phaseStatus` null, right?

Comment: Where do you get NullPointerException then? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I don't know what could be the problem, the code looks ok and I don't have the same setup here to be able to debug it for myself. Sorry I can't be of any more help.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time, I think I could complete the task with your solution. The syntax is correct, so as the returning value of the getter, I just need to figure it out why is the component not rendered.

Comment: Found the solution: I changed `Map<Integer, String> phaseColors` to `Map<String, String> phaseColors` and `<p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseColors[0]}" width="24px" height="24px" />` to `<p:graphicImage library="icons" name="#{bean.phaseColors['0']}" width="24px" height="24px" />` and it works! Maybe there's a problem with comparing Integer and int in EL expression. On the other hand I never had problems with comparing BigDecimal and int. Can someone explain that behaviour?